# How to replace the new line and line feed in a specific manner

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I have the below data in a column called as "DATA" in oracle.I was trying to remove the new empty line after each line .

- Input

  ```
  This is a text from line 1.

  This is text from line 2.

  This is a text from line 3.The line 3 ends here .

  This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .
  ```
- output

  ```
  This is a text from line 1.
  This is text from line 2.
  This is a text from line 3.The line 3 ends here .
  This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .
  ```

I have tried using

Query :

```
Select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(data,chr(13),null),chr(10),null) from main_data;
```

When i execute the below query the output is like a paragraph .

This is a text from line 1.This is text from line 2.This is a text from line .The line 3 ends here .This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .

Can any one say how to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25693951/7998591 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `'(' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '?|' || chr(10) || '){2,}'` regex:

```
select regexp_replace(
    'This is a text from line 1.' || chr(13) || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'This is text from line 2.' || chr(10)  || chr(10) || 'This is a text from line 3.The line 3 ends here .'  || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .',
    '(' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '?|' || chr(10) || '){2,}',
    '\1') as Result from dual
```

The pattern matches 2 or more (`{2,}`) consecutive repetitions of a CR symbol followed with an optional (1 or zero, `?`) LF symbol or (`|`) an LF symbol.

The match is replaced with the single, last matched occurrence of CRLF, CR or LF as `\1` is a placeholder for the value captured with the capturing group #1 (the first `(...)` construct in the pattern).

Output of the [online demo](http://rextester.com/BNUDZ33576):

[image]

Comment: Perfect . This works as a magic . In the query which you have provided ('\1') why are we using this ? .

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku The regex matches 2 or more consecutive linebreaks, and if we replace with `''`, we'll remove them and concat all lines into 1. We need to replace with a line break, and I showed how we may re-use the captured value in the replacement (see *`\1` is a placeholder for the value captured with the capturing group #1 (the first `(...)` construct in the pattern)*). You may hardcode it to `chr(10)`, or `char(13) || chr(10)` if you like.

Comment: BTW, you might want to use `'(' || chr(13) || chr(10) || '?|' || chr(10) || '){2,}'` to match all common line break endings: CRLF, LF or CR.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions and explanation this solution works perfectly for my question. ty.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are blank or `NULL` use the below.

```
SELECT DATA
FROM main_data
WHERE DATA IS NOT NULL OR DATA != ''
```

Comment: [DATA != ''] is redundant.that is never true because '' is treated as null in Oracle.

Comment: The OP seems to be talking about a single row value which is a string with embedded blank lines; not multiple rows some of which are null.

Answer (score 0):

How about you replace the the occurrence of consecutive end of line markers with just one.

```
DECLARE

  DATA VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  DATA := 'This is a text from line 1.' || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
          'This is text from line 2.' || CHR(13) || CHR(13) ||
          'This is a text from line 3.The line 3 ends here .' || CHR(13) ||CHR(13) ||
          'This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .';

  dbms_output.put_line(regexp_replace(DATA, chr(13) || CHR(13), CHR(13)));

END;
```

This will give you

```
This is a text from line 1.
This is text from line 2.
This is a text from line 3.The line 3 ends here .
This is a text from line 4.The line ends here .
```